Выполнить перенаправление с любого субдомена
server {
    if ($host = www.site.ru) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    if ($host = site.ru) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

}

Установил Certbot, он добавил свой блок.
Не понимаю для чего условие?
Если данный блок работает на соединения по http://
Почему бы просто не прописать.
server {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

Чтобы он в любом случаи перенаправлял на https:// Протокол.
Второй вопрос, возможно ли как то вне блока server, задать переменную. Допустим будет содержать  https://site.ru 
И перенаправлять
server {
    return 301 $site_url$request_uri;
}

Вся соль в том, что какой бы субдомен не ввести, сайт будет по нему открываться по http://
Точно также сайт открывается по https://, любой субдомен и сайт будет открыт только по http...
Очень хочется исправить это...

Можно и без условий, просто certbot не может быть уверен, что перенаправление с абсолютно любого домена является желательным для вас поведением

А второй вопрос непонятен

Со вторым вопрос прописал так, что перенаправление c http: будет в любом случаи. Сразу на без субдомена.  Как выставить правило, так чтобы определить что сайт открыт через субдомен? Не важно какой субдомен, выполнять перенаправление с любого...

Написать такой server_name, который будет охватывать все нужные вам (суб)домены, например через звёздочку или через default_server https://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/server_names.html
